# how to use current city and country in url in java?

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I am working on a project that provides some data with the help JSON API url through current location in base url

**my base url:**
`http://api.aladhan.com/v1/calendarByCity?city="+city+"&country="+country+"&method=2&month=04&year=2017`

Above i used two strings i.e city and country I want to get current location in city and country in strings and use it in base url like above

**please help me know the way to execute that and thank you in advance**

Comment: Take input from the user maybe?

Comment: I want it to auto detect

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) library for API call, then there is the concept of the query parameter. You just need to create the map and pass it to the API call function.

e.g.

```
@GET("v1/calendarByCity")
Call<ResponseT> groupList(@QueryMap Map<String, String> options);
```

where,
**ResponseT** is your API response model class, and
**options** is your query map given below.

```
Map options= new HashMap();
options.put("city","city_value");
options.put("country","country_value");
```

Comment: How can i get city, country value

Comment: you can either take input from the user or collect data from the current location of the user.

Comment: But i want it to be detect automaticly